# Extremely slow typesetting on TexShop and TexMaker even after reinstalling MacTex

Tags: texlive, typography, texshop, mactex

I am using the most updated versions of TexShop (5.12) and TexMaker (5.1.4) on a MacBook Air 13.6" running Mac OS Ventura 13.0. Even the simplest files (like this basic Overleaf beamer example below) now take approx 45 seconds to TypeSet on TexShop!

```
\documentclass[17pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\title[About Beamer] %optional
{Madrid theme + beaver}
\subtitle{Demonstrating larger fonts}
\author[Arthur, Doe] % (optional)
{A.~B.~Arthur\inst{1} \and J.~Doe\inst{2}}

\institute[VFU] % (optional)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Faculty of Physics\\
  Very Famous University
  \and
  \inst{2}%
  Faculty of Chemistry\\
  Very Famous University
}

\date[VLC 2021] % (optional)
{Very Large Conference, April 2021}

% Use a simple TikZ graphic to show where the logo is positioned
\logo{\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[color=red!50, fill=red!25, very thick](0,0) circle (0.5);
\node[draw,color=white] at (0,0) {LOGO HERE};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
%Highlighting text
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Demonstrating large fonts}

In this slide, some important text will be
\alert{highlighted} because it's important.
Please, don't abuse it.

\begin{block}{Remark}
Sample text
\end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have started experiencing such issues following some manipulations on the texmf folder for installing a new template (following online guides, including [this](https://www.ugr.es/%7Eftorralbo/blog/programming/local-texmf/)).
All I did was creating a folder /Users/usr/Library/texmf, and I have added in /Users/usr/Library/texmf/tex/latex a folder for a template [following this](https://github.com/sjewo/rub-beamer). I think this is all I did but I must have screwed something up and I am not sure what.

To undo everything, I have tried reinstalling both TexShop and TexMaker (by moving them to the trash, emptying it and then installing them anew), as well as uninstalling MacTex (trashing the folders in /usr/local/texlive and the TeX folder in /Applications and then installing it anew). The problem remains.

Comment: what happens if you open a Terminal and issue `pdflatex sample2e`?

Comment: It compiled very fast!

Comment: For comparison, with TeXLive 2023 (all packages updated), compiling from the TeXShop menu on my Mac Studio M1 Max took under 4 seconds. Compiling with `pdflatex filename` in Terminal took 3 seconds.

Comment: @murray if TeXShop scans the log file as for example Emacs/AUCTeX does this can explain the slight slow-down. A priori TeXShop is only a front-end wrapper on some underlying LaTeX distro, and one would need confirmation that the slowness is not observed from executing `pdflatex` or `lualatex` or `xelatex` also in Terminal (I don't know which engine is used) now that we know it is ok with sample2e.  Only explanation I can think of would be for TeXShop using (but how? why?) some latexformat with tracing enabled by default, then the log file will be gigantic and its parsing cause of slowness.

Comment: Actually, sample2e compiled rather fast on TeXShop too (3-4 seconds like @murray gets). However, I cannot understand why it takes 44-45 seconds for TeXShop to compile the simple presentation file that I posted originally, and almost just as much if I simply modify one letter. And unfortunately compiling it with `pdflatex` or `xelatex` from the terminal barely improves the compilation, if at all (43-44 seconds).